# GPT beam search length (number of tokens)

Tags: hyper-parameters, gpt, sentiment-analysis, prompt-design

**Background:** I'm currently trying to use GPT to give me numerical scores, and looking for tips on [prompt design, see my previous StackExchange post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/41581/prompt-engineering-gpt-for-numerical-scores).
To craft good prompts it seems important to have a good understanding of how the generative model works...

**Question:**
How many tokens ahead does GPT 3.5 look with its beam search feature?

**Extra context:** I found it hard to find good references for beam search, a decent starting point seemed to be [huggingface blog post](https://huggingface.co/blog/how-to-generate).
I tried asking BingChat about GPT-3.5 beam search length: BingChat replied that it was 10 tokens but could only give a 'reference' to an OpenAI API page which did not seem to support the claim. I couldn't find any other results online.

**Why I care?** Suppose I have a long theatre review and want to score how impressed the critic was by the quality of acting on a scale of: -5 extremely unimpressed to +5 extremely impressed.
My prompts currently ask the model to finish the reply with a sentence in the form:
"Overall the critic was very impressed by the quality of acting - score 4."
But perhaps by asking the model to continue generation I can make the prompts more reliable. E.g. I could ask the model to subsequently explain the score with a quotation from the text; e.g. along the lines of
"Overall the critic was very impressed by the quality of acting - score 4/5 - and indeed that 'Mark Strong's performance stole the show'"

Knowing beam search length would really help me design prompts like these (which ask for the continuation of text after a numerical score to improve reliability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get the connection between *Why I care* and Beam Search... it seems you are confused by what beam search is, since you talk about *beam search length*

However, beam search is about the width, not the length... at each timestep, the transformer outputs a distribution over tokens, thus for each token (for simplicity, think about them as words) you have a probability $p$ that that was the correct next word.

However, it's very hard for models to predict hard probabilities (0/1) since the data that it's been trained is noisy, so almost everything might come after everything

For this reason, if you just sample, you might sample a word that is with $p\approx 0$, but still greater than 0... for this reason, Beam search just limits this sampling on the next top-N words/tokens, thus at each timestep, you get the distribution over all the words, you take the top-N next words, you renormalize the distribution, and you sample from only those top-N words, avoiding going in area of the distribution that is unlikely just for a single bad sample

In other words, Beam search does not limit your output length, it's just a tradeoff between the greedy option (just take the most likely word) and the naive sample one (sample words according to the outputted distribution)

Comment: You are right! Thanks! Sorry for being an idiot! Yes I had misunderstood what beam search is. Presume I should keep the question up here? Or do you think I should take it down?

Comment: This (new/revised/correct) beam search understanding makes a lot more sense and is actually very useful for my project - so thank you for making me realise I had misunderstood!